# How to put a paragraph into a file?

Tags: c++

How to put the paragraph into file when user type the paragraphs?

```
   FILE *fp;
   char cmt[100];
   printf("Paragragh:  \n");
   scanf("%s",cmt);
   fp=fopen("cmt.txt","a");
   fputs(usern,fp);
   fputs(cmt,fp);
   fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using C programming?
You can try this.

```
char str[80];
  FILE *fp;

  if((fp = fopen("TEST", "w"))==NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open file.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  do {
    printf("Enter a string (CR to quit):\n");
    gets(str);
    strcat(str, "\n");  /* add a newline */
    fputs(str, fp);
  } while(*str!='\n');

  return 0;
```